# How to access a class instance from another method

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, instance

Here's my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 0, 0)];
  [self.view addSubview:view1];
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if([touch.view isEqual:self]) {
        CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
        self.view1.center = point;
     }
}
```

I want to be able to access the instance "view1" of the class "UIView" from the touchesMoved method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Save `rect1` as an instance variable.

Comment: This is not related to your question, but its standard in Objective C to start class names with capital letters (i.e. TempViewController and MyRect). This makes it easier to distinguish objects from classes.

Comment: Ok thanks! Will do. Now who gave my question a minus 1.... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare local variables as stated in the other answer. However, in my opinion its better to declare private properties in the anonymous category as below:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view1; // declares view1 as a private property
@end

@implementation ViewController 
@synthesize view1 = _view1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 0, 0)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.view1];
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if([touch.view isEqual:self])
    {
        CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
        self.view1.center = point;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `@synthesize` isn't necessary with the current compiler--it is generated automatically. The exception is properties declared `readonly`.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, there's supposed to be a star in front of the `rect1` property right?

Comment: @nielsbot I do the `@synthesize` so I have access to the `_propertyName` variable in the setter and getter methods. It makes it much easier to customize these methods.

Comment: No, no star. CCRect is not a object but a c struct.

Comment: And you indeed do not need to synthesize any property in modern compilers. This is done implicit.

Comment: @robhasacamera that makes sense for properties where you're writing your own setter/getter... but otherwise I would save myself the typing.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I was looking through my old questions and saw this. I think that `myRect` was some custom class of `UIView`, so I was using it as an object not a struct. I made some edits to fix the confusion; hopefully they will be approved.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `rect1` an instance variable by placing it in your `.h` file. You can do something like:

```
@interface tempViewController : UIViewController
{
      myRect *rect1;
}
```

Then in your `.m` file you will not have to declare it again.

Comment: Declaring an ivar directly in the header isn't current practice -- ivars should almost always be handled via declared properties.

Comment: or at least declare it in the `@implementation` as the modern versions of clang allows you to do that.